# How to select a random Entry on a tkinter canvas?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, random

I'm making a simple sudoku generator, and have got 81 different entries `(e1, e2, e3, e4 ... etc)`.
I would like to know if there is any way to select a random entry to insert a number into.

So kind of like this:

```
num = randint(0, 81)
entry = "e" + str(num)
entry.insert()
```

With the above code you get an error saying
`str object has no attribute 'insert'`
which makes sense, but is there any way to 'convert' a string to a variable name?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/ "Stack Overflow"). In order for us to help you, it is necessary that you show your effort.  Please provide a minimal reproducible problem set consisting of sample input, expected output, actual output, and all relevant code necessary to reproduce the example. What you have provided falls short of this goal. Please edit your question to show a minimal reproducible set. See [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") for details on how to best help us help.

Comment: @romke you can use dict  for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the entries in a list, then use `random.choice` to pick one of the entries.

```
entries = []
for i in range 81:
    entry = tk.Entry(...)
    entries.append(entry)
...
random_entry = random.choice(entries)
```